# how to I redirect both code file and terminal output to the same output file (simulating python repl)?

Tags: python, linux, bash, terminal, console

I would like to save the input code and the output result into a file. For example the following python code `code.py`:

```py
print(2+2)
print(3+2)
```

to create a `code-and-output.txt`:

```sh
>>> print(2+2)
4
>>> print(3+2)
5
```

But I can not get it working. Basically, I want to `code-and-output.txt` to capture what would happen if I run interpreted python and run statements in python interactive environment (code + output).
Ways that I have tried so far:

### Redirect stdout:

`python code.py > code-and-output.txt`
It only saves the output.

### Redirect stdout and stdin:

`python < code.py > code-and-output.txt`
It does the same (only output).

### nohup

`nohup python code.py`
The same problem: only output.

### Script

```
script -q code-and-output.txt
python
print(2+2)
print(2+3)
ctr+d
ctr+d
```

It works but I need to do it manually. Moreover, it saves some garbage that I can not make them quiet with -q.

### Bash Script

```sh
# bash-file.sh
python &
print(2+2)
print(2+3)
```

Does not work: commands run in console bash, not python. It does not work with `&` either: never ends python repl.

### Using tty

open another terminal like `/dev/pts/2` and send above bash-file.sh

```sh
cat bash-file.sh > /dev/pts/2
```

It just copies but does not run.

I am not interested in solutions like Jupyter and iPython. They have their own problems that does not address my requirement.

Any solution through linux commands (preferably) or python? Thank you.

Comment: see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/420983/1277357) for redirecting output, but in short: `SomeCommand 2>&1 | tee SomeFile.txt`

Comment: It creates exactly the same output as in `python code.py > output.txt`: it does not include the code itself. The problem is that `python code.py` has a different output than running code inside python interactive terminal.

Comment: I misunderstood your question, apologies. Can you provide another example? The first `code-and-output.txt` doesn't actually match the input you mention above it. Do you want the interactive python interpreter input and output catched completely?

Comment: Yes, exactly. To capture in a file what happens if I do manually:
```
python
>>> print(2+2)
4
>>>print(2+3)
5
>>>exit()
```
The problem is that `python code.py` only prints the output.

Comment: yes, because the code inside code.py doesn't actually get printed anywhere, it gets interpreted. There's a big difference bewtween the 2. I think what you want to achieve is not possible easily. You would need to build your own interpreter as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save this is as `repl_sim.py` in the same directory as your `code.py`:

```py
with open("code.py", 'r') as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        print(f">>> {line.strip()}")
        eval(line)
```

Then run in your terminal with the following if you want to redirect the output to a text file named `code-and-output.txt`:

```py
python repl_sim.py > code-and-output.txt
```

**-OR-**

Then run in your terminal with the following if you want to see the output as well as the make the text file matching:

```py
python repl_sim.py  | tee code-and-output.txt
```

It at least works for the example you provided as `code.py`.

---

**Pure Python version of first option above so that you don't need shell redirect.**
Save this code as `repl_sim.py`:

```py
import contextlib
with open('code-and-output.txt', 'w') as f:
    with contextlib.redirect_stdout(f):
        with open("code.py", 'r') as input_file:
            for line in input_file:
                print(f">>> {line.strip()}")
                eval(line)
```

Then run in your terminal with:

```py
python repl_sim.py
```

That will result in `code-and-output.txt` with your  desired content.

Contextlib use based on [Raymond Hettinger's August 17th 2018 Tweet](https://twitter.com/raymondh/status/1030160198600548352) and [contextlib.redirect_stdout() documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout)
.